# Python pygmentize ignores style options

Tags: python-3.7, pygmentize

I'm trying to syntax highlight Python 3 code with the `pygments` `pygmentize` command line program, but it just ignores all the style options. I have tried the following:

`pygmentize -S colorful -l python3 e:\work\Python\repl.py`
`pygmentize -O style=colorful -l python3 e:\work\Python\repl.py`

It either gives back the help text or the default styling. This is on Windows 10. Anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

It also returns the help when trying to write out an html file using:

`pygmentize -f html -S colorful -l python3 -o a.html e:\work\Python\repl.py`

Comment: `pygmentize -O style=colorful -l python3 e:\work\Python\repl.py` should work. Is `colorful` listed when you run `pygmentize -L styles` ? All lowercase?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Pygments version 2.11, `pygmentize --help` states the following:

```
  -O OPTION=value[,OPTION=value,...]
                Give options to the lexer and formatter as a comma-separated list of key-value pairs. Example: `-O bg=light,python=cool`.
  -P OPTION=value
                Give a single option to the lexer and formatter - with this you can pass options whose value contains commas and equal signs. Example: `-P "heading=Pygments, the Python highlighter"`.
```

It was not obvious to me, but I've used `style` as an option and it worked with both `-O` and `-P` :

```sh
pygmentize -O style=colorful -g /etc/hosts
pygmentize -P style=friendly -g /etc/hosts
```

Reminder : to list available styles, run `pygmentize -L styles`